# google maps v3 toggle draggable property of markers fetched from SQL database

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-maps

I have multiple markers fetched from MYSQL database and I've put them on the map this way where i put the values in a html form in php and pass it in to addmarker function to create the markers:

```
function initialize() 
{
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), 
    {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(25.230828, 118.041382),    
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeControl: true
    });

    <? //PHP PART

        // Do a mysql_query 
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * from temple");

        if(mysql_num_rows($sql))
        {
            // get values from mysql_query and add on to map
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
            {

                $id = $row['id'];
                $rom_name=$row['rom_name'];
                $chi_name=$row['chi_name'];
                $lat=$row['lat'];
                $lon=$row['lon'];


                $html = '<div id="form_container" style="margin:0px;border:0px solid red;Width:521px;height:330px;">'.
                        '<form name="edit_existing" action="phpedit.php" method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">'.                           
                            '<input type="hidden" style="display:none" name="update_id" value ="'.$id.'"/>'.
                            '<input type="text" name="update_chi_name" value ="'.$chi_name.'"/></td>'.
                            '<table class="form_table" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-size: 0.90em; border:none 0px #cacaca; margin-bottom:0">'.
                            '<td style="padding:4px 0px 2px 0px"><input type="text" name="update_rom_name" value ="'.$rom_name.'"/></td>'.
                            '<input style="margin-left:8px;float:right" type="submit" name="delete_data" onclick="confirm_delete()" value="Delete this data"/>'.                                '</form>'.
                        '</div>';                               

                echo ("addMarker($lat, $lon, '$chi_name', '$html');\n");

            }
        }

    ?>

}

//ADD MARKER TO THE MAP
function addMarker(lat, lng, name, info) 
{
    var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    bounds.extend(pt);

    var marker = new MarkerWithLabel  // using MarkerWithLabel utility library
    ({
        icon:icon,
        position: pt,
        draggable: false,
        raiseOnDrag: true,
        map: map,
        labelContent: name,
        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 28),
        labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
        labelStyle: {opacity: 1},
     });

    var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow
    ({
        maxWidth: 800
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() 
    {
        popup.setContent(info);
    });
}
```

Now, I would like to add a button on the html form to allow users to toggle the draggable property of a marker so that the users can drag that marker and update its new position by submitting the form. How do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a reference to the markers that are on the map. Once you have created the marker you can just push it into an array. Then when you want to set one as draggable you can just call setDraggable on it:

```
var markers = {};

function addMarker(lat, lng, name, info) 
{
    var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    bounds.extend(pt);

    var marker = new MarkerWithLabel  // using MarkerWithLabel utility library
    ({
        icon:icon,
        position: pt,
        draggable: false,
        raiseOnDrag: true,
        map: map,
        labelContent: name,
        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 28),
        labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
        labelStyle: {opacity: 1},
     });

    ...

    markers.push(marker);
}
```

And then when you want to make a specific marker dragable:

```
markers[i].setDraggable(true);
```